# Allow simple path for new users to gain small rep by reviewing guidelines?

Tags: discussion

New users tend to jump right into asking a question. If anything, that is probably the reason they made their account - for access to the awesome community here. However, sometimes new users stumble a little on their first question by accident.

I think that if they had read more of the documentation here - such as the *[help vampire page](http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/)*, Jon Skeet's *[Writing the perfect question](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints)*, the *[stackoverflow faq](https://stackoverflow.com/faq)*, the *[meta faq](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq)*, the *[faq for all stack exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites)*, etc. - that they would fare a lot better.

Would it make sense to give out 1 rep per examination of each of these articles for new users as an incentive to learn about the guidelines, rules, etc? I know that there is not currently a framework in place to facilitate that, so I am not exactly sure what other way to offer the exams would be, but it seems like it be a win win scenario to give new users a tiny amount of rep for reviewing important documentation.

Comment: You can already get the Analytical badge for reading the full faq. (Well, visiting it at least)

Comment: @Bart - Good point, badges are good incentive. I am not sure if rep would be a good idea, so I thought I would just see what others thought.

Comment: @Bart I'm not sure why, but I have never been awarded that badge. And believe me, I've tried. </badgewhore>

Comment: @mikeTheLiar - Read the FAQ. Click on every topic link, expand everything.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar I just clicked all the links on the right side.

Comment: @Oded I know how it's *supposed* to work. I've just never been awarded it (yet).

Comment: I'm ambivalent about this. While I like education, much of this material boils down to "be considerate;" it's all far too long, and some things can only be learned by tripping over them anyway.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar, yeh, took me quite a while to get that one to show up.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - I like your comment, it seems to answer the question (specifically with regards to the issue of learning by doing) and there does not seem to be much to add here. Can you please migrate it to an answer. I tried flagging it to indicate it could be an answer but I had already upvoted your comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is all a new user needs to know to become productive right away on Stack Overflow (it's in the https://stackoverflow.com/about page):

[image]

While I'm all for education, much of the material you linked boils down to "be considerate" and "have a little common sense."  It's all far too long for the first-time user, and it's not intended for them anyway.  It's intended for those folks who need a bit of remedial training in how to interact properly with other professionals in a Q&A setting, not a forum.

Answer (score 2):

We should give them enough rep to make comments (50 on SO) if they get through it all (i.e. earn the Analytical badge), which will have the added benefit of cutting down on new-user Meta posts about not being able to make comments.

Comment: The Analytical badge can be earned by visiting all sections, not necessarily reading any content. I'd say we leave the rep privilege in place for some actual proof and deal with the occasional question here on Meta

Comment: I think this is too much rep to hand out at first all at once in my opinion, I was thinking smaller amounts. 50 rep is equivalent to a bounty.

Comment: @Travis, remember that we give out 100 rep to any user who joins another SE site.

Comment: @LanceRoberts - True, but that is still with the caveat that you must have already earned 200 rep on your own.